# Winform passing data between user controls

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I have windows form application which has several user controls - each one is displayed when the relevant option is selected from a listbox.

Some of the user controls need to have access to data stored in a different user control so User Control A needs to know a value of a textbox stored in User Control B. I have done my exposing some properties in the user control B.  This all works fine when the application first loads and no values are changed.

The problem I am having is if the value of the textbox in user control B is changed it is not picked up by user control A.

Do I have to do something with NotifyPropertyChanged?  Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you show us code you have made for this? It will greatly help us help you.

Comment: What do you mean by exposing from UserControlA to UserControlB? Maybe the class that instantiated the usercontrols should manage the transfer of property values?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions here:

- Create a series of public properties and handle passing values where the `Form` objects are newed up.
- Create an `event` to communicate when things change and register an event handler in the target `Form` to accept the change. This is similar in theme to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface but that's only required/advised for formal databinding scenarios.

I prefer events for this kind of thing.